# Google Analytics using same tracking ID in sub folders

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website lets say http://www.example.com which is on shopware and uses google analytics to determine site traffic. I have designed a landing page which is placed at http://www.example.com/landing/index.html. Can I use the same tracking id that I have on other pages on my landing page? Will it appear under all website data section or will it create another automatically?

**Actual website is not at example . com its just for reference purpose.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. The Google Analytics web tracker is client side code, it does not really care if your pages have been created by a shop system or by manually entering code somewhere. By the time it is displayed in the browser it's all just HTML.

The data will show up in "All Website data" (which is the only view GA ever creates automatically, everything else you need to set up yourself as needed).